# How Do I Get My Application on the Debian Package Manager

Tags: debian, package-management, repository

https://github.com/alexanderepstein/Insomnia

I wrote a cross platform application under the electron framework and I have both a 32 and 64 bit debian package installer (.deb files). They don't install with a double click but running

```
sudo dpkg -i file.deb
```

does work. I want to try to get my application on the debian repo so for linux users that want to install it can run

```
sudo apt-get install myappname
```

I want to do this just to learn about the process of how to go about this for the future. After some research I've read about about getting a mentor to sponsor your package on the repository but i don't really think i have the required files to go that route at that moment. Can anyone clear up this process for me?

Comment: This seems too distro specific. You should submit a request to the distribution packagers, in this case Debian.

Comment: @Bob For now you are correct it is just a debian version however I am looking to create an rpm installer as well I just need to figure out a bug I've been having. But do you have any advice as to how i go about submitting a request, where do i start this process what do i need other then my .deb to actually get on the package management system.

Comment: There is information in [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/16456/215267). I suggest reading through _all_ of the provided links in the Debian section because packaging and maintaining a package to distribution guidelines is generally hard.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/devel/ - and as a long time debian user let me say thank you for trying to help make debian better

Comment: Regarding the RPM packaging that you mentioned - it is not just RPM vs Deb, each distribution is different, so for example, you would need different packages for Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, RHEL, openSUSE, Arch, Gentoo, and so on.

Comment: Thank you both @Bob and ivanivan for the links. Although after slightly looking at them i think you may have been right and its harder than I thought. I was looking to use it as a way to have my package be auto updated with a an update and upgrade command through the package manager. Is there an easier way to do this with an unoffical repository, just so it didn't have to meet guidelines, my application is pretty harmless? Additionally if i have a .deb file I thought it would install on both debian and ubuntu (i use elementary os) same way i thought rpm would install on fedora and cent os?

Comment: Each prebuilt package, such as RPM or Deb, work on only a certain distribution, and often only a certain _version_ of it. One of the reasons is configuration paths. Often you would need to specify what packages your own package depends on. On a fast moving distribution like Fedora, SUSE Tumbleweed, Arch, or Gentoo the versions of these dependencies may change quickly and you should update your program to use the latest ones. On distributions like Debian and RHEL these dependencies are updated only to minor versions so you would have to backport your bugfixes to work with older dependencies.

Comment: @Bob Is there any chance that the electron framework circumvents those issues about making it version specific. From what I understand my application has all of its dependencies built into it and doesn't actually use any files on the system. I clearly don't know enough to say that definitively however the huge push of the electron framework is it's ability to work on all platforms and configurations.

Comment: Before you contact the distribution maintainers, try making your own repository for your package. On Ubuntu, there are [PPAs, Personal Package Archives](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas). On Fedora, there is [Copr](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/). On Arch, there is [AUR, Arch User Repositories](https://aur.archlinux.org/). On Gentoo, there are [Overlays](https://overlays.gentoo.org/).

Comment: Using a framework like that would make it semi-independent from the platform, like a container, so it may be easier to update, yes. However, I have never used it, so YMMV.